# Null recurrence of a Random Walk in a Random Environment

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

Let $W_0^+,W_1^+,...$ i.i.d random variables on $[0,1]$ and $W_0^-:=1-W_0^+,...$.

Suppose that X, given W, is a random walk on $\mathcal{N}_0$ with transition probabilities $p_i(x,x+1)=W_i^+$, $p_i(x,x-1)=W_i^-$ and, if $x=0$, the process cannot go to to the negative integers but it stays in $0$.

How I can show that X is **null recurrent** if $E[\log{\frac{W_0^-}{W_0^+}}]=0$?

I know that X is recurrent from [Solomon (1975)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-3/issue-1/Random-Walks-in-a-Random-Environment/10.1214/aop/1176996444.full). To prove the null recurrent property I tried to obtain some recurrent equations with no success because, at the end, I get an expected value that involves both the "$W$"s and some other expectation conditioned on those "$W$"s.

Please, let me know if more context is needed. Thanks for the help.